# Why do I have to specify a return value if the function is already guaranteed to either return or throw?

Tags: java, exception

I don't have to specify a return value in a function that is guaranteed to throw an exception because that path is dead:

```
// Works fine!
public boolean a() {
   throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

I don't understand why I can't do the same here:

```
// Error: This method must return a result of type boolean
public boolean a() {
   try {
      return mayReturnOrThrow();
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
      new RuntimeException(ex);
   }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your `catch` block doesn't *throw* an exception, it just creates one and then ignores it, so the catch block would then complete and you're reach the end of the method without returning anything.

Comment: This should have been the answer, not a comment, Jon. But I guess you want to let others have the chance to get the points.

Comment: I think we should close it as a typo, the OP is perfectly aware how it's supposed to work, just missed a word... Cheers!

Comment: @MichaelPiefel: I was effectively thinking of it as more of a typo question, as per Andrew's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new RuntimeException(ex);` just makes an exception and then does nothing with it - it's a useless no-operation. You'd want to throw it:

```
throw new RuntimeException(ex);
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was missing something very subtle.The logic error was behind the keyboard.